# Unwanted overlap / gap between 2 shapes in a grid? Expression Blend

Tags: xaml, user-interface, wpf-controls, expression-blend, blend

In expression Blend, I'm trying to create a rectangle button that has a corner cut out and, when the button is resized, the cut corner should remain the same.  I believe that the best way to do this would be to create 3 shapes (2 rectangle shapes and 1 triangle path) and force them together in a grid.  I've also set the stroke to none.

However, there is a slight (but noticeable) gap / overlap between the shapes leaving lines where they join.  The problems becomes apparent when the fill has an alpha applied (which I need for the design).

Could you take a look at the code and see what the problem is (it's currently just a grid before I make it into a control).  Or maybe there's a better way to create this rectangle button with a corner cut (and the cut corner doesn't resize).

```
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="350" MinHeight="60">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="17"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="17"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Path Data="M0.5,0.5 L16.5,16.5 0.5,16.5 z" Stretch="Fill" Width="17" Height="17">
                <Path.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#7F000000"/>
                </Path.Fill>
            </Path>
            <Rectangle Margin="0" Grid.Row="1">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#7F000000"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>
        <Rectangle>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#7F000000"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?